# C++ [] mapping, possibly through templates

Tags: c++, templates, struct, operator-overloading, dynamic-data

I have a little problem in C++ I don't know how to solve.
The first part of the problem is to access an element in a struct via [], or better, to map [] to a subelement.

My struct looks like this:

```
struct e {
    std::string content;
    std::string name;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<e> > elements;
};
```

If I want to access a subelement of e, I can do this like this: `e.elements["e1"][0].elements["e1sub"][0].content`, would it be possible to map this so I can call it like this: `e["e1"][0]["e1sub"][0]`, this would just mean that he has to "replace" every e[] with e.elements[].

Maybe this can be done with templates but I don't know how to use them yet as I'm just beginning to learn C++.

Thanks in advance for any help, Robin.

Comment: Isn't a `vector<e>` technically illegal within `struct e` (vector of incomplete type, though depending on implementation details you can get away with it)?

Comment: Recommend making `elements` a private/protected member in addition to all suggestions given below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to overload `operator[]`. Typically, you want to implement two versions of that operator, but since `std::map` only overloads the non-`const` version, that might be enough for you.

Something like the following should do:

```
struct e {
    std::string content;
    std::string name;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<e> > elements;

    std::vector<e>& operator[](const std::string& key) {return elements[key];}
};
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but if you're overloading operators, maybe it's time to put the data into a real class?

Answer (score 2):

You can "overload" the [] operator, try:

```
struct e {
    std::string content;
    std::string name;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<e> > elements;
    std::vector<e>& operator [](const std::string& s);
};

...

std::vector<e>& e::operator [](const std::string& s) {
    return elements[s];
}
```

Comment: In C++ there is absolutely no need for `typedef struct e {...} e;` - that was only necessary in C.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need templates. You merely need an `operator[]` :

```
std::vector<e>& e::operator[](std::string const& s) { return this->elements[s]; }
// elements.operator[s] inserts s if it doesn't exist yet. That's non-const so the following won't work
// std::vector<e> const& e::operator[](std::string const& s) const { return this->elements[s]; }
```

Comment: The `const` version would have to be much more elaborate than that for `std::map`. Also, implementing it you'll face the same problem that lead to `std::map` not having a `const` overload of `operator[]()`. And you need to upgrade your spill chucker. `:)`

Comment: 1) You didn't attribute your comment answer and I only came by here accidentally. 2) I don't know what "ofc" stands for.

Comment: @sbi: I didn't attribute the comment since it wasn't a response. I added a comment for other readers, so they would not be misled to believe that your comment applies to the latest code. "ofc" stands for "of course", which I believed to be a common abbreviation.